# decomposition of representation kG of G

Tags: representation-theory

> Decompose $kG$ in to indecomposable representations and decide which summands are irreducible.
>
> (a)$G=S_2,k=\mathbb{C}$
> (b)$G=\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z},k=\mathbb{C}$
> (c)$G=\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z},k=\mathbb{F}_3$

**ideas**: Maschke's Theorem tells us that (a) and (b) are completely decomposable, but (c) is not. For (a): If $S_2=\{e,s\}$, then $span(e),span(s)$ should be the subrepresentations.
For (b) and (c) I have no idea, how does $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ act?

Comment: Assuming $kG$ is viewed as a the "regular" module structure then $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ acts by left multiplication.

Comment: i.e. if we have $2c+1d\in kG$ and $2$ acts on it, we have $2.(2c+1d)=1c+2d$?

Comment: Well a typical element of $kG$ in case c) has the form $\alpha1_{G} + \beta x + \gamma x^{2}$ where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in k$ and $x$ is a generator of the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: What always confusing me is, are we speaking about $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ as an additive or multiplicative group?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ is only a group with respect to addition (if you consider the standard addition), e.g. $0$ is not multiplicatively invertible. But if we consider the group algebra, then it is helpful to write the group law multiplicatively, since otherwise you might confuse it with the addition in $kG$ as a vector space. This can be done for example by identifying $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ with the group of third roots of unity.

Answer (score 0):

As was already answered in the comments, the action is always left multiplication (or right multiplication, depending on your preference of left or right modules).

Some hints:

(a): $\operatorname{span}(e)$ is not a subrepresentation of $kG$ in this case since $s\cdot e=s\notin \operatorname{span}(e)$. But you are right, this two-dimensional representation is the direct sum of two one-dimensional representations. To find out which ones, take an arbitrary element of $kG$, i.e. $\alpha e+\beta s$ for $\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb{C}$. Now multiply with $s$, then you get $\beta e+\alpha s$, but this should be in the span of $\alpha e+\beta s$. So the question is, what can you choose $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to be in order to satisfy that.

(b): The idea is the same as in (a), only now you have a three-dimensional representation with basis $e, s, s^2$. Here you also need to use complex numbers, whereas in (a) $\mathbb{Q}$ would suffice.

(c): That's a bit trickier. I'll give to hints: 1) This representation is indecomposable. 2) Consider powers of the element $(1-g)$, where $g$ is a generator of the group.